# error to run training job with aws Sagemaker

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to use my own sickit-learn ML model with SageMaker using the github example.

The python code is below :

```
# Define IAM role import boto3 
import re 
import os 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
from sagemaker import get_execution_role 
import sagemaker as sage from time 
import gmtime, strftime 
role = get_execution_role()

ess =  sage.Session()
account = sess.boto_session.client('sts').get_caller_identity()['Account']
region = sess.boto_session.region_name
image = '{}.dkr.ecr.{}.amazonaws.com/decision-trees-sample:latest'.format(account, region)


output_path="s3://output"

sess

tree = sage.estimator.Estimator(image,
                      role, 1, 'ml.c4.2xlarge',
                     output_path='s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/output',
                    sagemaker_session=sess)

tree.fit("s3://output/iris.csv")
```

But I get this error :

> INFO:sagemaker:Creating training-job with name:
>   decision-trees-sample-2018-04-24-13-13-38-281
>
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ClientError                               Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        14                     sagemaker_session=sess)
>        15 
>   ---> 16 tree.fit("s3://inteldatastore-cyrine/iris.csv")
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py
>   in fit(self, inputs, wait, logs, job_name)
>       161             self.output_path = 's3://{}/'.format(self.sagemaker_session.default_bucket())
>       162 
>   --> 163         self.latest_training_job = _TrainingJob.start_new(self, inputs)
>       164         if wait:
>       165             self.latest_training_job.wait(logs=logs)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/estimator.py
>   in start_new(cls, estimator, inputs)
>       336                                           input_config=input_config, role=role,
>   job_name=estimator._current_job_name,
>       337                                           output_config=output_config, resource_config=resource_config,
>   --> 338                                           hyperparameters=hyperparameters, stop_condition=stop_condition)
>       339 
>       340         return cls(estimator.sagemaker_session, estimator._current_job_name)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker/session.py
>   in train(self, image, input_mode, input_config, role, job_name,
>   output_config, resource_config, hyperparameters, stop_condition)
>       242         LOGGER.info('Creating training-job with name: {}'.format(job_name))
>       243         LOGGER.debug('train request: {}'.format(json.dumps(train_request, indent=4)))
>   --> 244         self.sagemaker_client.create_training_job(**train_request)
>       245 
>       246     def create_model(self, name, role, primary_container):
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py
>   in _api_call(self, *args, **kwargs)
>       312                     "%s() only accepts keyword arguments." % py_operation_name)
>       313             # The "self" in this scope is referring to the BaseClient.
>   --> 314             return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
>       315 
>       316         _api_call.**name** = str(py_operation_name)
>
> ~/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py
>   in _make_api_call(self, operation_name, api_params)
>       610             error_code = parsed_response.get("Error", {}).get("Code")
>       611             error_class = self.exceptions.from_code(error_code)
>   --> 612             raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
>       613         else:
>       614             return parsed_response
>
> ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling
>   the CreateTrainingJob operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::307504647302:assumed-role/default/SageMaker is
>   not authorized to perform: sagemaker:CreateTrainingJob on resource:
>   arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-1:307504647302:training-job/decision-trees-sample-2018-04-24-13-13-38-281

Can you help me to resolve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: what attempts have you tried to resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you don't have access to the resource

```
arn:aws:sagemaker:eu-west-1:307504647302:training-job/decision-trees-sample-2018-04-24-13-13-38-281
```

Can you check if the resource url is correct and the proper permissions are set in the security group.

Comment: Thank you @Raman , as i am a beginner with aws, can you help me how can I check this?

Comment: Did you get it.. or still need help?

Comment: still need help. Thank you

Comment: If you want to use SageMaker's images, you need to set up permissions. Go to the IAM resource. If you want to use your own machine learning model, you have to create a customized image using Docker: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

Comment: Hi @Nasri, I'm facing the same problem and apparently I'm unable to make new IAM role because my AWS account is provided by AWS Educate. Is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using AWS Educate account.

At this time you cannot use SageMaker service to create a training or modeling job with an AWS Educate Starter Account.

At the present time, you can use your own personal AWS account if you'd like to use/deploy a training job with SageMaker service.

You can however continue to use Jupyter notebooks via SageMaker through AWS Educate account.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing similar problems when I started using SageMaker so I developed this open source project https://github.com/Kenza-AI/sagify (sagify), it's a CLI tool that can help you train and deploy your own Machine Learning/Deep Learning models on SageMaker in a very easy way. I managed to train and deploy all of my ML models whatever library I was using (Keras, Tensorflow, scikit-learn, LightFM, spacy, etc). Essentially, you can specify all your dependencies in the classic pythonic way, i.e. in a requiments.txt, and sagify will read them and install them on a Docker image. Then, this Docker image can be executed on SageMaker for training and deployment.

Additionally, I specify in the sagify docs (https://kenza-ai.github.io/sagify/) a one-off process on how to setup your AWS account in order to avoid permissions related issues.